# Is there any way to add meta attributes via CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm assuming this is not possible, by design, but my options are limited on this.

Basically, I'm trying to make a site scale correctly on mobile devices. The site is built through a vendor's platform, and so I only have access to CSS and most HTML. It strips out any JS and certain HTML (e.g. head, meta, etc.)

The problem is that they did not include the magic scaling code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

So while I'm able to make pages more responsive on a desktop experience, the mobile experience does not scale.  As such, media queries haven't been especially useful either.

Is there any way to fix this? Something with CSS? Pseudo elements? iFrames?

Comment: Does "most HTML" not include the head?

Comment: Switch to a vendor that allows valid code.

Comment: @WillThresher It strips out any head tags

Comment: @DrewKennedy That's the dream...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to add meta attributes via CSS?

No.

> Something with CSS?

No.

> Pseudo elements?

Are non-semantic and add only visual effects.

> iFrames?

Would embed another document and could not touch the `<head>` of the current document.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured.